# Разложить в ряд Фурье функцию, заданную таблично и построить график нескольких гармоники

Tags: python, фурье

Есть функция, она задана таблично:

```
X 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Y 0 1 2 2 5 4 3 0
```

Примерный исходный график прилагаю: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо построить несколько гармоник. Как я понимаю, это должно выглядеть подобным образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только как это сделать для моей функции? Можете подсказать? Заранее вам спасибо.

Код на python для построения исходной функции:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import splrep, splev
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
Y = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 5, 4, 3, 0])

# Построение сплайна
tck = splrep(X, Y)

# Генерация новых точек для интерполяции
x_new = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
y_new = splev(x_new, tck)

# Визуализация результатов
plt.plot(X, Y, 'o', label='Исходные данные')
plt.plot(x_new, y_new, 'b', label='Сплайновая интерполяция')

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

Comment: что изменилось после этого вашего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1525090/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4-%d0%a4%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8c%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be ? Вы, кстати, так и не приняли ответ на него.

Comment: В предыдущем вопросе вы поняли что такое `ak` и `bk`?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Да.

Comment: Хорошо. А как связаны `ak` и `bk` и волнистые линии на картинке в этом вопросе?